# Why does it show IndexError: string index out of range?

Tags: python

```
list = (input('Enter your list(number only) : '))
def scorefunction(score):

    length = int(len(list))
    maxs = length + 1
    test = 0
    n = 0
    while test < maxs:
        if list[n+1]<list[n]:
            scorefinal = score
             n = n + 1
             test = test + 1
        else:
            scorefinal = score + 1
            n = n + 1
            test = test + 1
    return scorefinal 

print(scorefunction(0))
```

i am trying to create a function that compare a number with the number in front of it, and if the number is smaller than the number in front of it, we get one score. example : 5823.

we get 1 score here because 8>5 while other are smaller like 2<8, 3<2.

Comment: Try to change `while test < maxs` to `while test < maxs + 1`. Because inside your loop, you're calling the n+1 element which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all 3 isn't smaller than 2 and therfore the score for 5823 need to be 2. :D

**Problem and explanation**

Regarding your question the answer is `maxs = length + 1` is the problem. I don't know why you use variable `length` (and why you cast it to `int`, because `len()` always returns an `int`). However `length` is equal to `len(list)`, with `list` beeing your string.

Your variables `test` and `n` are redundant so let's replace `test` in the loop-condition with `n`.
Now you can see that you access `list[n]`, with `n` being smaller than `maxs`. **The largest value for `n` will therefore be `len(list)` which simply is out of range** (as `IndexError: string index out of range` clearly shows).

In python strings are arrays of characters. And **arrays of length `n` are indexed from `0` to `n-1`**. Accessing element at index `n` will result in an `IndexError`.

**How to solve the problem**

**Remove the `maxs` variable and replace it's occurences with `length`** (which itself could be replaced with `len(list)`. That will solve the `IndexError`.

Additionally (has nothint to do with your problem) consider removing either `test`or `n` as they are redudant.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You are using the variable name "list", which is a built-in keyword in Python. Thus, you should choose another variable name.
2. The input from input() is treated as a single string. To convert it into a list of numbers, you need to split it and then convert the elements to integers.
3. In the while loop, you compare elements of the list, but the index n+1 can exceed the index length, which would result in an error.

This is an adjusted version of the code:

```
your_input = input('Enter your list (numbers only) : ')
your_input = [int(num) for num in your_input]

def scorefunction(score):
    length = len(your_input)
    maxs = length - 1
    test = 0
    n = 0
    scorefinal = score
    while n < maxs:
        if your_input[n+1] < your_input[n]:
            scorefinal = score
        else:
            scorefinal = score + 1
        n += 1
        test += 1
    return scorefinal 

print(scorefunction(0))
```

But note, 3 is larger than 2. This function returns 1 as soon as a number from your input is smaller than its successor. The score remains at 1 if there are several such combinations in your input. However, if the score should specify the number of such combinations, it must be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: From what i had understand, there a while loop and for example if my input is 10 character, then it should repeat 8 times, with that the score should be either stay the same or increment. But why does it stay at 1 despite having more combination. I know you said that it should be adjusted accordingly however since i'm new to programming, i couldn't find what wrong.

Comment: You use scorefinal = score and scorefinal = score + 1 in your while loop . However, score is your input variable from the function, which is always the same. So if score = 0, scorefinal in the while loop will be in each iteration either 0 or 1.
How you can adjust this:
        if your_input[n+1] < your_input[n]:
            pass
        else:
            scorefinal = scorefinal + 1